# Style textContent of the parentElement

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to JavaScript and  have a problem with changing the color of the textContent of buttons with the `nextElementSibling` property.

I thought

```
e.target.childNodes.nextElementSibling.textContent.style.color = white
```

would work but it didn't.

I am using it like this:

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text and provide a [mre].

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do, can you please provide more details as to what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: textContet returns the string value, it is not a reference to the text

Answer (score 1):

You use the `style` property with a DOM Element and not with `textContent` property! Remove `textContent` from your code to make it work:

```js
e.target.childNodes.nextElementSibling.style.color = "white";
```